# How to find everything starting with "customfield_" in JSON data

Tags: jquery, json

I have this unsorted JSON-data coming from Atlassian Jira which I get via GET-request:

```
[
   {
      "id":"customfield_10000",
      "name":"Konzeption",
      "custom":true,
      "orderable":true,
      "navigable":true,
      "searchable":true,
      "clauseNames":[
         "cf[10000]",
         "Konzeption"
      ],
      "schema":{
         "type":"number",
         "custom":"com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float",
         "customId":10000
      }
   },
   {
      "id":"priority",
      "name":"Priority",
      "custom":false,
      "orderable":true,
      "navigable":true,
      "searchable":true,
      "clauseNames":[
         "priority"
      ],
      "schema":{
         "type":"priority",
         "system":"priority"
      }
   },
   {
      "id":"customfield_10001",
      "name":"Umsetzung",
      "custom":true,
      "orderable":true,
      "navigable":true,
      "searchable":true,
      "clauseNames":[
         "cf[10001]",
         "Umsetzung"
      ],
      "schema":{
         "type":"number",
         "custom":"com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float",
         "customId":10001
      }
   }
]
```

I just want to have the "id" of each "customfield_#####". How can I search through the JSON to get each ID of each custom field?

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://json.org) but an array of objects. Just use the regular `Array` methods like `.map()`

Comment: What have you tried so far and what do you have problems with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're not defined you programing language i will post a little examples her with different languages hope will help you.

First PHP:

```
<?php
$j ='[
{
    "id":"customfield_10000",
    "name":"Konzeption",
    "custom":true,
    "orderable":true,
    "navigable":true,
    "searchable":true,
    "clauseNames":[
        "cf[10000]",
        "Konzeption"
    ],
    "schema":{
        "type":"number",
        "custom":"com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float",
        "customId":10000
    }
},
{
    "id":"priority",
    "name":"Priority",
    "custom":false,
    "orderable":true,
    "navigable":true,
    "searchable":true,
    "clauseNames":[
        "priority"
    ],
    "schema":{
        "type":"priority",
        "system":"priority"
    }
},
{
    "id":"customfield_10001",
    "name":"Umsetzung",
    "custom":true,
    "orderable":true,
    "navigable":true,
    "searchable":true,
    "clauseNames":[
        "cf[10001]",
        "Umsetzung"
    ],
    "schema":{
        "type":"number",
        "custom":"com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float",
        "customId":10001
    }
}
]';
$j = json_decode($j);
foreach($j as $o){
    echo (strpos($o->id, "customfield_")!==false)?'ok':'none';
}
```

Now Javascript:

```
var j = '[{"id":"customfield_10000","name":"Konzeption","custom":true,"orderable":true,"navigable":true,"searchable":true,"clauseNames":["cf[10000]","Konzeption"],"schema":{"type":"number","custom":"com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float","customId":10000}},{"id":"priority","name":"Priority","custom":false,"orderable":true,"navigable":true,"searchable":true,"clauseNames":["priority"],"schema":{"type":"priority","system":"priority"}}, {"id":"customfield_10001","name":"Umsetzung","custom":true,"orderable":true,"navigable":true,"searchable":true,"clauseNames":["cf[10001]","Umsetzung"],"schema":{"type":"number","custom":"com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.customfieldtypes:float","customId":10001}}]';
    j = JSON.parse(j);
    for(o in j){
        console.log ((j[o].id.indexOf("customfield_")>=0)?'ok':'none');
    }
```

If you need more examples, fill free to comment good look.

Comment: The language is defined: jQuery, that is Javascript. just look the tags that the question is marked

Comment: in this case we must help save time and give good answer no just follow tags, as jquery is based on javascript and they are made to facilitate the use of javascript, and when you can use javascript easily why complicate using other things?

Comment: Thanks, that JavaScript does exactly what I want :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use forEach(function) to enumerate every child nodes in you array!
    //Let's say your data is in an Array (as you mentioned!)
    yourData.forEach(processEachNodes);
                  //As ForEach is an function for Arrays, thus you can only
                  //Use it if you data is an array, fortunately, it is!

```
function processEachNodes(myNode, index, rawObject){
    if(myNode.id.indexOf("customfield_") === 0){
        //DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
}
```

After you get a child node, you may know how to process these IDs, whatever the condition you want.

Comment: the question is tagged with javascript, no need for informations about C# or python, it just confuses others that come to look for an answer. Also, the asker actually have an array, not a JSON (looking at the structure that he posted in the question)

Comment: Thx, and already removed C# and Python things, but he said that it is "unsorted JSON-data". anyway, that doesn't actually have impact on the method of processing the data ,